# c# foreach: send request to server and get response

Tags: c#, events, foreach

How i can send request to server in foreach and when i get response - do something whith information which i get. When information process is done, continue foreach.

My problem: in foreach i send much request and foreach continue whithout process with information which i get in response.

For example:

```
 foreach (DataLoader.GetInfo items in listBoxFetInfo.Items)
 {  
     DownloadInfo(items.CompanyName);                     
 }
```

and

```
void DownloadInfo(string name)
{
  //Send request 
}
```

and

```
feed.RequestCompanyName += new IFeedEvents_RequestCompanyNameEventHandler(feed_RequestName);
```

and

```
void feed_RequestName
{
//get information and save to file
}
```

Comment: can you show a block of code for how you process a single item?

Comment: @RufusL now this code is very simply, for example> listbox.items.add(name);

Comment: @RufusL now i have: foreach { send request} and get response out of this foreach, i wanna have: foreach {send request - this is first void, and get response - second void and this second void do something with information}

Comment: @alexander: What parameters does void feed_RequestName take? Does this method take response received from request to process it?

Comment: I use dll and can write: in void: SendRequest(string name) and in second void - feed_RequestName for examle i get country for this company. Save this in file and continue foreach

Comment: My problem is that if i write listbox.Items.Add() in this two void, i see in this listobx: send;send;send;get;send;send;send;get;get;get;get;send but i wanna: send;get;send;get;send;get.

Comment: i need in wait when second void will finish and send new request in foreach

Comment: @RufusL understand me?)

Comment: @EbadMasood understand me?)

Comment: @alexander: I think you should look at Peyman's approach.

Comment: @EbadMasood yes, i read some information about Task and may be it can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different solution for this approach, but one of them is using Multiple Async Tasks and try to download each url in separate Task and after downloading the file successfully handle the result. For more information you can see this link:

[Start Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/jj155756.aspx)