# Wait For Asynchronous Events to Finish in Foreach

Tags: c#

How can I send a request to server using foreach and when i get response then for foreach wait for the returned information to process before continuing on to the next request.

My problem: in foreach I send many requests and foreach continues without process with information which i get in response.

For example:

```
foreach (DataLoader.GetInfo items in listBoxFetInfo.Items)
{  
    DownloadInfo(items.CompanyName);                     
}
```

and

```
void DownloadInfo(string name)
{
   int requestId = feed.SendCompanyNameRequest(symbol.ToUpper(), sendType, sendTimePeriod, sendDateFrom, DateTime.Now);
}
```

and

```
feed.RequestCompanyName += new IFeedEvents_RequestCompanyNameEventHandler(feed_RequestName);
```

and

```
void feed_RequestName(int originalRequestId, short ResponseCode, string symbol, short symbolStatusCode, object records)
{
//save to file
}
```

I can't use [Start Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/jj155756.aspx)  because this solution need in add CancellationToken where i can not add (can not in void feed_RequestName

What another solution can be in this problem?

Also, i can not change signature of:

```
feed_RequestName(int originalRequestId, short ResponseCode, string symbol, short symbolStatusCode, object records)
```

and

```
feed.SendCompanyNameRequest(symbol.ToUpper(), sendType, sendTimePeriod, sendDateFrom, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: I think that we might need a little more information. What is `DataLoader`? What is `feed`? Are they something you wrote or some library? Does `SendCompanyNameRequest` execute in another thread or is it a blocking call?

Comment: @LosFrijoles feed is library, dataLoader is my constructor when i create list which will be load informations for item in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a stab in the dark here as to how your thing works, but this is what I would do. Since you can't modify the signatures, you can't use `Task`, like your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737945/c-sharp-foreach-send-request-to-server-and-get-response) suggested.

What I see here is that you have a method that begins a request and then an event that is called when the request is completed. I'm assuming your request is running on a separate thread or something inside the library where `feed` is from. What you need to do is wait for that event to complete once before proceeding to the next item. If this isn't what your question is asking or how your library works, let me know.

If you are **not** executing the requests in parallel (meaning only one is executing at a time and nobody else is using your `feed` object), you can use the `System.Threading.ManualResetEvent` class to make your one method depend on the other really easily. What you can do is the following:

1. In your `DownloadInfo` method, `Reset` the `ManualResetEvent` so that whenever somebody calls `WaitOne`, it will "block" the thread and prevent it from going on. It will wait until somebody else calls `Set` on the `ManualResetEvent`.
2. After calling the method that gets your `requestId`, call `WaitOne` on the `ManualResetEvent`. This will wait until "somebody else" calls `Set` on the `ManualResetEvent`.
3. In your `feed_RequestName` method, `Set` the manual reset event once you are done processing. This will make the `WaitOne` that you called in step 2 stop blocking and continue. If you store the results of the request in some variables on the object that these things live in before calling `Set`, you can access the results from your `DownloadInfo` method after the `WaitOne`.

A short, incomplete example:

```
class YourClassWhereYouPutTheseThings
{
    private ManualResetEvent _mre = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    //...your other stuff here...

    public YourClassWhereYouPutTheseThings()
    {
        //...your existing stuff
        feed.RequestCompanyName += new IFeedEvents_RequestCompanyNameEventHandler(feed_RequestName);
        //...your existing stuff
    }

    void YourMethod()
    {
        foreach (DataLoader.GetInfo items in listBoxFetInfo.Items)
        {
            DownloadInfo(items.CompanyName);                     
        }
    }

    void DownloadInfo(string name)
    {
        this._mre.Reset(); //make everyone listening to _mre wait until Set is called
        int requestId = feed.SendCompanyNameRequest(symbol.ToUpper(), sendType, sendTimePeriod, sendDateFrom, DateTime.Now);
        this._mre.WaitOne(); //wait for the feed_RequestName method to be called once
    }

    void feed_RequestName(int originalRequestId, short ResponseCode, string symbol, short symbolStatusCode, object records)
    {
       //save to file

       //store your information on the object somewhere if you would like

       //after saving to your file, set the manualresetevent so that the WaitOne() above can proceed
       this._mre.Set();
    }
}
```

**Important note**: If your `feed` is shared among multiple objects which could execute at the same time, you need to make sure that you don't interpet requests by other objects as the request that your `DownloadInfo` method made. Any request will cause your `feed_RequestName` method to be called, so you need to figure out which call of that method corresponds to your request. Here is one suggestion on how to make that work:

1. Store the `requestId` that you get in your `DownloadInfo` somewhere that `feed_RequestName` can access. This could be problematic if `feed_RequestName` gets called before your calling method has a chance to execute. You will need to figure out a way around this problem.
2. In `feed_RequestName`, compare against the stored request id and only call `Set` on the `ManualResetEvent` if it matches.

**Another note**: Your library is geared towards executing requests in parallel. Waiting for the request to finish before going to the next one is really inefficient. What you should really do is something like (psuedocode):

```
DownloadItems:
    Lock the object so that only one person uses the method at a time
    foreach item in requests
        call your start request method and get the id
        put the id into a thread-safe set stored on the object
    wait for the set to become empty

feed_RequestName:
    Do your thing that you've been doing
    Remove the id from the thread safe set
```

Comment: when i click start, my programm is not responding, may be because _mre.Reset?

Comment: in main class i create void: public void SetMre(){_mre.Set();} and use this in feed_RequestName which in another class. it's true?

Comment: do how you write and this work, thanx a lot, but have some function: when i start programm, my programm is not responding. Can i start in another thread this? for example in foreach i have: this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { ProgressDataLoad.Value++; })); and this does not work

Comment: main problem was: i send about 1000 request, but can about 250, now this problem - not problem because work)

Comment: What is the library that is providing `feed`? The method I showed in this answer will only work if that library is starting another thread to do the request on. It was a guess that the library was starting threads or executing jobs on a threadpool. You need to use the debugger and step through to see if your `feed_RequestName` method is being called and find out when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use while instead of foreach?

Like:

```
while(not done processing all requests) {
  //grab and process next request
}
```